# Swift - How to pushViewController in userNotificationCenter without Storyboard

Tags: swift

I'm implementing the push notification feature with Firebase.

For the last part, I'd like to make a link to a NavigationController page when notification is tapped.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    var parentController: UINavigationController?
    let destinationVC = SomeNavigationController()

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    if let maeesageId = userInfo["maeesageId"] as? String {
        destinationVC.maeesageId = maeesageId
        parentController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }

}
```

With the codes, when I tap on a notification, it doesn't crash but it bring me to a rootViewController page.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to navigate to a page further down in the navigation stack?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: @coonie u r moving to ViewController with tab bar embedded

Answer (score 0):

In your `rootViewController`, set a boolean flag to check whether it is presented by push notification. If it is, navigate to the next view controller in `viewWillAppear` of your `rootViewController`

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    var isPresentedByPushNotification = false

    override viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if isPresentedByPushNotification {
            //Set the flag to false so that you don't end up in a loop
            //when you press back on the next view controller
            isPresentedByPushNotification = false

            //Navigate to the next view controller here
        }
    }
}
```

When you receive a notification, before pushing the `destinationVC`, set the flag to true

```
destinationVC.isPresentedByPushNotification = true
```